# How to Detect Memory Leaks on QNX？

Tags: memory-leaks, address-sanitizer, qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

I've tried valgrind, it seems to have difficulties working effectively on ARM64 QNX.
I've also attempted to use sanitizers. When I add '-fsanitize=address' during compiling, it compiled failed.

```
undefined reference to `__asan_report_load1'
undefined reference to `__asan_option_detect_stack_use_after_return'
undefined reference to `__asan_stack_malloc_2'
undefined reference to `__asan_report_store4'
undefined reference to `__asan_stack_free_2'
...
```

So, I would like to know the compatibility of Sanitize with QNX. Are there any other ways to detect Memory Leak on QNX.

Answer (score 0):

QNX includes a heap analysis toolkit - this is probably the best place to start.

https://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog/topic/hat.html